# why navigation works when link is typed in search bar but not with button click in Angular?

Tags: redirect, routes, navigation, click, angular8

In my code, written in angular 8 navigation works well when the path is searched from search bar or given with **routerLink** from anchor tag. But it redirects to empty path after a sudden # symbol when I try to navigate using button click with router.navigate.

**router navigation not working with button click.**

here is the part of my html code

```html
<a class="card" href="#">
  <div class="card__background" style="background-image: url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1509/8876/products/Women-2018-Autumn-Fashion-Casual-Long-Shirt-Workwear-Office-Formal-V-Neck-Top-Striped-Tie-Waist_grande.jpg?v=1571441092)">
  </div>
  <div class="card__content">
    <h3 class="card__heading">Women's Clothing</h3>
    <button (click)="inToWomen()" type="button" class="btn btn-light">Add to Women's Clothing</button>
  </div>
</a>
```

here is my relevant inToWomen function which is called on button click

```html
inToWomen() { this.router.navigate(['/addDress/women']); }
```

here is my routing on routing.module.ts

```html
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin', component: ViewComponent},
  { path: 'admin/addDressMen', component:MenComponent},
  { path: 'admin/addDressWomen', component:WomenComponent}
  
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a pretty simple error.

In my html component I have add the button within the anchor tag. so the click function doesn't work and it navigates to # which is the link mentioned in anchor tag. when I replaced the anchor tag with div tag and removed href="#" then the click method worked fine and routing was success.

here is my corrected html component

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__background" style="background-image: url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1509/8876/products/Women-2018-Autumn-Fashion-Casual-Long-Shirt-Workwear-Office-Formal-V-Neck-Top-Striped-Tie-Waist_grande.jpg?v=1571441092)">
  </div>
  <div class="card__content">
    <h3 class="card__heading">Women's Clothing</h3>
    <button (click)="inToWomen()" type="button" class="btn btn-light">Add to Women's Clothing</button>
  </div>
</div>
```